# Memory error at drop rows from pandas data frame

Tags: python, performance, pandas, large-data

I have a big data frame, 26M lines of data on 9000 persons.
indices are not ordered.

I need to run few calculation on the data of each person separately,
and save it to new  data frame, one line per person.

I wrote a loop on the unique persons id, extracted small data frame with
 this person's data, run the calculation on it, and save results to a 
pre-defined data frame. The calculations are mainly sum and divide operation 
on columns under specific conditions.

This took around an hour on Amazon linux server. not practical.

To make it more efficient, I tried to delete the current person 
from the data frame, so data frame decrease in size will increase efficiency.
I got a memory error after 2-4 steps.

I manage to reconstruct the problem on my laptop-windows. 
The problem occurs only if data frame size is large enough. on my laptop from 4000000.
resetting the indices, solved the problem for this size, but memory problem repeated in larger size of 40000000.

I am newbie in large data sets, and newbie in pandas, 
Any idea will be appriciated

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import random
random.seed(50)
np.random.seed(50)
size = 4000000
dtype = [('view_day', 'int32'), ('account', 'int32'),('category', 'int32'),
         ('Col1I','int32'), 
         ('Col2I','int32'),('Col3I','int32'),
         ('Col4F','float32'), ('Col5F','float32'), ('Col6F','float32'),
        ('isFull','int32'), ('islong','int32')]
values = np.ones(size, dtype=dtype)

index = np.arange(size)

np.random.shuffle(index)

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index)
df['view_day'] = np.random.randint(7605, 7605 + 180, df.shape[0])
df['account'] = np.random.randint(1548051, 1548051 + 100, df.shape[0])
df['category'] = np.random.randint(1, 5, df.shape[0])
df['Col1I'] = np.random.randint(600, 1200, df.shape[0])
df['Col2I'] = np.random.randint(1, 600, df.shape[0])

accounts= df.account.unique()

for w in accounts:
    dfs = df[df.account == w]#.copy() - both versions causing memory error

    print dfs.shape
    print df.shape
    df.drop(dfs.index, inplace=True)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7c390ede93df> in <module>()
      4     print dfs.shape
      5     print df.shape
----> 6     df.drop(dfs.index, inplace=True)

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in drop(self, labels, axis, level, inplace, errors)
   1876             else:
   1877                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
-> 1878             dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   1879             try:
   1880                 dropped.axes[axis_].set_names(axis.names, inplace=True)

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in reindex(self, index, columns, **kwargs)
   2739     def reindex(self, index=None, columns=None, **kwargs):
   2740         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(index=index, columns=columns,
-> 2741                                               **kwargs)
   2742 
   2743     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2227         # perform the reindex on the axes
   2228         return self._reindex_axes(axes, level, limit, tolerance, method,
-> 2229                                   fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
   2230 
   2231     def _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value,

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   2685         if index is not None:
   2686             frame = frame._reindex_index(index, method, copy, level,
-> 2687                                          fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   2688 
   2689         return frame

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   2696         return self._reindex_with_indexers({0: [new_index, indexer]},
   2697                                            copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value,
-> 2698                                            allow_dups=False)
   2699 
   2700     def _reindex_columns(self, new_columns, copy, level, fill_value=NA,

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   2339                                                 fill_value=fill_value,
   2340                                                 allow_dups=allow_dups,
-> 2341                                                 copy=copy)
   2342 
   2343         if copy and new_data is self._data:

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in reindex_indexer(self, new_axis, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_dups, copy)
   3595             new_blocks = [blk.take_nd(indexer, axis=axis, fill_tuple=(
   3596                 fill_value if fill_value is not None else blk.fill_value,))
-> 3597                 for blk in self.blocks]
   3598 
   3599         new_axes = list(self.axes)

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in take_nd(self, indexer, axis, new_mgr_locs, fill_tuple)
    994             fill_value = fill_tuple[0]
    995             new_values = algos.take_nd(values, indexer, axis=axis,
--> 996                                        allow_fill=True, fill_value=fill_value)
    997 
    998         if new_mgr_locs is None:

C:\Users\naomi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.pyc in take_nd(arr, indexer, axis, out, fill_value, mask_info, allow_fill)
    928             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype, order='F')
    929         else:
--> 930             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
    931 
    932     func = _get_take_nd_function(arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis,

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Was this problem solved?